# showing all data from database table in html table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table where 3 row in there.each data is different. I tried to show full database table in HTML table, but it shows one data 3 times.

```
$query=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT entrydate,day,discription,highlight,place from datatable");
$insert=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$countrow=mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

here is code for showing table...

```
<?php
If ($countrow > 0) {
    for($i=0;$i<$countrow;$i++) {
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $insert['entrydate']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $insert['day']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $insert['discription']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $insert['highlight']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $insert['place']; ?></td> 
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>
                <a href="#" class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```

my output is
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAONe.png)

Comment: You are not using the i variable from the loop

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` belongs _inside_ the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove:

```
$insert=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Then change the for loop into a while loop:

```
while ($insert=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
```

This will cause $insert to be populated with each result on each loop until none remain.

Comment: thank you!! it's working.
but i am not clear this concept.can you please tell me little more?